# what is the event for longpress in vb.net datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events, mouseevent

How can I handle a `long press` in a cell/row in datagridview in vb.net?

I know how to handle events like `click` and `double click`. But I dont know how to handle a `long press`.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start a timer on the mouse down event, stop it on the mouse up event, and draw you conclusion :)

Chew Chew:

```
Private ClickTime As DateTime

Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseDown
    ClickTime = Now
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseUp
    If (Now - ClickTime).TotalMilliseconds > 500 Then MsgBox("LongClick")
End Sub
```